# How to fetch data from a different sql server database without having access?

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have two databases A and B in same SQL Server instance.. I need to write a trigger -- After update of a table in database B it will fetch data from few tables of database A and then insert data in some table of database B .. The issue is the user who will be accessing the database B does not have access to database A .. If I write a trigger with 'sa' account, will it work when the user inserts some data in database B? Also let me know the scenario what would I have to do if database A is in a different SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

It ***can*** work, but you have to do a few things to get there.  Here's the easiest way (though not necessarily the best):

1. Set the owners of both Databases to 'sa'.
2. Turn on CROSS-DATABASE chaining for both databases.
3. Turn on TRUSTWORTHY for the source database (B).
4. Edit the Trigger and add `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` before the FOR clause.

Note that while this works, it has significant security considerations (particularly #2 and #3).  Here is a link that explains this and some other methods and some of the security issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304.aspx